# Is it possible to predict which atom will reflect which frequency of E.M wave?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, reflection, quantum-optics, spectroscopy

as we know some elements let some specific frequencies of light transmit through them while others will absorb them or reflect( scatter) them ! So i wanted to know that is there any way to predict which elment or atom will reflect which frequency ? as we have emissions spectrum for different elements, is it possible to predict something like reflection spectrum ?

Any help will be appreciated !

Comment: The reflection spectrum of a material depends on its structure as well as its chemical composition. Graphite and diamond clearly do not have the same reflected spectrum!

Comment: Well , do they have same emmission spectrum ?